# Convert JSON function into AJAX/JQuery function

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like some help taking this php code that I will post below into a JQuery/AJAX function. I would also like to know how I can call the function in the second code that I will post.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ncic_names WHERE name LIKE 
    '%" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY name ASC");

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $data[] = $row['name'];
    }

echo json_encode($data);
```

Here is where I would like the new javascript function to be called into

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#ncic_name").autocomplete({
        source: 'search.php'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not at all understanding what you are asking to do here... care to elaborate?

Comment: What you're doing looks like it should work. Check the Network tab in developer tools to see if the returned JSON looks correct.

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery UI library so you get the Autocomplete widget?

Comment: @IncredibleHat Sure thing. I want to be able to have this with other functions so that it doesn't have to be in one file and I need it to be in a Ajax/JQuery function and not how it is.

Comment: @Barmar The issue isn't that it doesn't work, it does work.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking. This **is** AJAX/jQuery. When you use a URL as the `source:` property, it performs an AJAX request. If you want the jQuery code to be in another file, just put it in a `.js` file that you load with `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`

Comment: @Barmar Can it be put into a function that is on the same page?

Comment: Of course it can. Just put it into a function and call it when you want.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I know pretty much nothing about Ajax or jQuery. How would I call it on the autocomplete function as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.get` to perform the AJAX call yourself:

```
function search_ncic(name, callback) {
    return $.get("search.php", {term: name}, callback);
}
```

The `callback` function will be called with the returned array as its argument. And since this returns the promise that `$.get` returns, you can also use `search_ncic(name).then(...)`.

Comment: I definitely miscommunicated this. I want the function for the database grabber. The autocomplete function can stay, I just want the other part of the same page or a way to put it with PHP functions without having issues with it happening.

Comment: I don't understand. What "other part"? You can't put the PHP and JS code together, they run on different machines at different times.

Comment: The part that gets the information from the database. I want to be able to have other things with it, currently, if I put it on the main page it runs it so I only want it to run when I start typing.

Comment: OK, I think I understand what you're asking, I've replaced my answer.